# Using jquery to disable a field if another field has a value (dynamically)

Tags: jquery

I want to disable input2 if the user starts typing a value into input1.

If there is no value in input1 (for example if the value is deleted), I also want input2 to be re-enabled.

Here's what I wrote so far, but it's not working.

```
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">

<script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            if($('#input1').val())
            {
                $('#input2').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind "input" and "propertychange" like so:

```js
let secondInput = $('#input2'); // Cache the jQuery element
$("#input1").on(
    "input propertychange",
    event => secondInput.prop(
        'disabled',
        event.currentTarget.value !== "")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
```

This works even with copy/paste, dragging in, and all other methods.

`propertychange` is not a must, but it is for IE support.

Comment: What does the `propertychange` part do? Isn't the `input` event enough to cover typing, copy/paste, etc.? Note that if you're keen on succinct code you can replace the if/else with a one-liner with `secondInput.prop('disabled', event.currentTarget.value != "");`

Comment: @nnnnnn Took your advise regarding the one liner. propertychange is IE crap. There's all browsers, and there's IE. I hate IE.

Comment: Additional question. I noticed it didn't work when the field already has existing input. How would I alter it so that the 2nd field is disabled if the 1st field already has content inside?

Comment: @kevinkt oh, just start with it being in a disabled state. Add `secondInput.prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Just chain `.trigger("input")` on the end of the above and it should run the code once to cater to blank or non-blank value at page load.

Comment: @nnnnnn also a possibility, true. I like you mr. lots of n's.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't the second input to be disabled when the first is changed you can listen for keyup and change the disabled to true. In the example i only do it if the first input is not empty.

```
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#input1').on('keyup', function(e){
            if(e.target.value.length > 0){
              $('#input2').prop('disabled', true);
            }else{
              $('#input2').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What if the user changes the value without using the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

This answer included the good aspects of above answers

```
<input id="input1" type="text">
<input id="input2" type="text">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#input1').attr("disabled", true);
        $('#input2').on("input propertychange", function (e) {
            if ($('#input2').val()) {
                $('#input1').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#input1').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the good aspects"? Please explain why your answer is better than the others.